# knitr::include_graphics() disables slide break operator (---) in xaringan

Tags: r, xaringan

When I include an image in a xaringan deck using `knitr::include_graphics()`, my page break operator (`---`) fails, and the next slide merges into the previous slide.

Here is a reprex demonstrating the problem:

````
---
title: "knitr::include_graphics() disables slide break operator (---)"
date: "2022-01-04"
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

# This slide break will work

---

# But when my slide has an image, the slide break will fail

```{r out.width='30%'}
knitr::include_graphics("hp.jpg")
```

--- 

# This should have been a new slide

```{r out.width='30%'}
knitr::include_graphics("hp.jpg")
```
````

[image]

Comment: The problem is that there is a space after `---`  if you remove the space, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem!

Comment: I just love semantically significant whitespace. Ugh.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, post as answer? (I don't think I'd close this as "due to a typo", as it could indeed be a useful answer for other people)

Comment: When you want to insert a horizontal rule into the slide, you would need the trailing space. The slide separator must be strictly three dashes without spaces. There needs to be a way for remark.js to differentiate between the separator and the rule. More info: https://yihui.org/en/2018/07/yue-jiang/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a that xaringan is very picky about what page breaks look like.  In the example above, there is a whitespace after the second `---` which is causing the problem.  Removing he whitespace will fix the error.

Comment: what if theres no space after the --- and  its still happening ?

Comment: can you post the relevant contents of the .Rmd file so we can try to reproduce?  Also, what versions of R and xaringan are you using?